# What field on the Task object is its parent?

Tags: sharing, tasks

The org I'm working in has its org wide defaults for sharing as "Controlled by Parent". After looking at the [Task object documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_task.htm), I think its the WhatId or WhoId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's both. If the user can view the Who or What, they can also view those activities.

Comment: Is any lookup field or master-detail field on an object considered a "parent" field?

Comment: @TylerZika For custom objects, you can have one or two master-detail relationships that count as parents; no lookup field is ever considered a parent. For standard objects, the rule is whatever the "primary" parent would be, even if that field is a lookup field. For example, Opportunities has Account as a parent, but it's not a required field. You have to read the documentation to figure out what qualifies as the parent for a given object. Other than Activities, most standard objects have either 1 or 2 parent types that are parents.

Comment: @TylerZika To clarify, I mean "parent for purposes of sharing settings." In normal RDBMS (Relational Database Management Systems), the parent of a record is defined by the child's lookup field to the parent (i.e. every child has one parent, and one parent may have many children).